# calling jasper report from Rest web service

Tags: plsql, jasper-reports

I have a problem with calling jasper report from web service.

I used this URL http://host:port/jasperserver[-pro]/rest_v2/reportExecutions to get request id ,and  the output was something like following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportExecution><exports><export><id>ee83c20b-6c3b-4299-88cb-57cc771aa7e2</id><outputResource><contentType>application/xls</contentType><fileName>myreport.xls</fileName><outputFinal>true</outputFinal></outputResource><status>ready</status></export></exports><reportURI>/reports/my_reports/myreport</reportURI><requestId>78183e2a-3740-4706-a058-a4d94508a9ad</requestId><status>ready</status><totalPages>1</totalPages></reportExecution>
```

Now I'm trying to run jasper report by the following url

http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_
v2/reportExecutions/78183e2a-3740-4706-a058-a4d94508a9ad/exports/ee83c20b-6c3b-4299-88cb-57cc771aa7e2/outputResource

But this URL does not work properly. The question is How can I reform the URL to call the report?

Actually I need to call jasper report from oracle apex application but I don't want to use opal-consulting method to integrate oracle apex and jasper report I simply want to call a web service in PL SQL

I tried this URL --http://host:port/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/[path to the report].[format]-- it works for me but it prompts user to log into jasper server. On the other hand this URL returns the report file, I need to have a URL to Download the output.

Could you please tell me how to call jasper report to generate output download link.

corresponding to jasper server Documents, it is possible to make a request and run a report in URL....you can find the documents here   [http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v610/running-report-asynchronously-0][1]

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why do you need a request id to get the reports.
Try this URL
http://host:port/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/[path to the report].[format]?